# Facebook OAuth redirect_uri to page tab error

Tags: facebook, oauth

I am following this tutorial http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/
and specifically at this part of code

```php
 $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
 
 $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);
```

When I enter `$canvas_page` as

```
$canvas_page = "http://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/app_APP_ID/"
```

I get an `"Error occured. Try again Later"`

If I enter Canvas Page Url instead, it shows the canvas page correctly but I do not want that.

I am sure that it was working last week, so I do not know what is wrong now.

Comment: When you look at the app on https://developers.facebook.com/apps, what is the "Canvas URL" value? I think they need to match. Also, I don't think you want to put a facebook.com URL there, you want the URL of the app on your own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was previously working was this

```php
$canvas_page="http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE_NAME/PAGE_ID?sk=app_APP_ID"
```

but since I changed the app to a namespace I had to do something like this:

```php
$canvas_page="http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/"
```

and it now shows up correctly without error

Answer (score 7):

For me the problem was the GET request, somehow it seems facebook asks for the GET parameter, I will show you what I mean:

I had this:

```
uri = "http://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_appId";
```

When I changed it to the below it started working:

```
uri = "http://www.facebook.com/pagename/?sk=app_appId";
```

Hope this helps someone as it helped me.

Comment: Is this documented? What actually happens in the backend?

Comment: Well, here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/ they say the page tab must be in this format https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID it is very easy (in my opinion) make a mistake and assume that a clean url  would do it

Comment: This worked for me, but the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) (at the time of writing) says otherwise: "The URL you specify must be a URL of with the same Base Domain as specified in your app's settings, a Canvas URL of the form https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE or a Page Tab URL of the form  **https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID**"

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, this should work - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/

What won't work is redirecting directly from Canvas App -> Auth Dialog -> Page Tab
but Page Tab -> Auth Dialog -> Page Tab should work fine with that documentation

Answer (score 0):

In the app settings, try put TAB URL in:

app on facebook -> canvas URL

In the secure URL too

Put in here WITH Slash at the end, BUT in your REDIRECTION put WITHOUT slash at the end.